# Will main thread catch exception thrown by another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

If I have code like this:

```
try
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(wc.LocalRunProcess));
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //do something with ex
}
```

Will the exception thrown by thread `t` be caught in the catch block?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. It will not catch any exceptions in your other thread `t`. You will have to catch them in that thread and deal with them appropriately.

However, I believe the AppDomain's UnhandedException event will report it.

Comment: `Application.ThreadException` for WinForms, `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` for WPF and `AppDomain.UnhandledException` to be specific.

Comment: @xbonez, Also to expand, the code in the question will start the new thread then continue processing right past the catch block while the new thread just starts executing.

Comment: @John: Aah, true. Didnt think of that before.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker!  It has exception and cancellation handling.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer the question.  No the catch will not get exceptions from another thread.  The BackgroundWorker was designed to cope with this situation.

Comment: Are you saying that the `BackgroundWorker` will catch an exception that crosses threads.  For instance if in the `RunWorkAsync` you call a method that starts another thread and that thread has an exception, will it be handled by the `WorkCompleted` event?  I am trying that and it appears not to catch it.

Comment: RunWorkAsync will run the code on another thread, so there is not need to start another thread.  It will only catch exceptions on the thread it is running on.